# check if name of encoding is valid

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a method that reads user input 'encodingString' and then encode file using

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(string encodingString)
```

This method throws an exception if not a valid `encodingString`.
How to check if `encodingString` is a valid code page using the simplest way? I can use  `Encoding.getencodings` method and check if it has our encoding. But is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there a simpler way?

Basically no.
If you need to validate that encoding name is valid you can either

- Load all encodings through `Encoding.GetEncodings()` - however you need to pay attention to name / code page / display name / etc.
- parse within `try\catch` block - if it fails you have 100% certainty that it wasn't valid. Even if ugly it may still be feasible in your case

  ```
  try
  {
   var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(string encodingString); 
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      throw new InvalidEncodingException(encodingString);
  }
  ```

Comment: Couldn't find an easier/nicer way either. The code that would make it possible without exception handling is unfortunately internal.